# Toggle click function on list of items in AngularJS (iframe)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-ng-click

So I have the below work-flow:

I've got a **list of items** each having an `ng-click` event which **opens an iframe** below the item clicked. Now,

- On clicking an item of the list, a `div` tag below that item displays *(initially hidden)* which contains an `iframe`.
- Now on clicking another item from the same list, another `div` tag displays below the recent item clicked, which in turn displays the `iframe` for the recently clicked item.

The **issue** that I'm facing is this -

On clicking an item of the list, if any `div` tag containing the `iframe` is currently open, it gets closed and the `div` tag along with the `iframe` of the recently clicked item displays.

*Currently, if any iframe is open, on clicking an  other item from the list, a new iframe of the recently clicked item opens along with the initial iframe still remaining open. The initial one getting closed only after I've clicked on it.*

What shall I do?

*PS: I hope the scenario is clear, let me know if further clarification is required.*

**Edit-**

Posting a jsfiddle link is kinda tough as this question is a part of a huge folder I'm working on. But, I'll post the code here and hope that it will suffice.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="data in JsonData">
    <div class="row" ng-click="getGraph(data.id, $index)">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
            <span id="title">Title: &nbsp;{{data.name}}</span><br><br>
            <span style="color: #000 !important">
                <strong>Id:</strong> &nbsp;{{data.id}}
            </span><br/><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-left" style="color: #000 !important;">
            <span style="text-align: left; font-size: 13px;">
                  <strong>Details:</strong> {{data.details}}
            </span><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="iframe col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins ibox_shadow">
                <iframe style="width: 80%; height: 50%; id="targetframe" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ng-src="{{graphUrl | trustAsResourceUrl}}">
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the **controller.js** code:

```
$scope.getGraph = function(d,i) {
        $scope.graphUrl = 'http://server-url.com:8888/path/to/theGraph?id='+d;
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(d);
        $(elem).toggleClass('class_to_toggle_hide_show');
}
```

Comment: Can you show code? It would be better if you post your code on jsfiddle

Comment: Can u update your code in jsfiddle or plunker and post here...It will be easy to help then..There is too much content to read and understand in your question J

Answer (score 0):

If you post the code it will clear it more. But in the ng-click event you can first say ng-click="youfunction($event)"
and

```
$scope.yourfunction = function(event){
   $(even.target).find("iframe").remove();
   //and then your other stuff here  

}
```